# My ProgressBar does not appear on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar

I have this code for the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="15px"
>
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Loading..."
/>
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar"
android:paddingTop="10px"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:max="100" />
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/txt"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then for the class :

```
public class Loading extends Activity {
     ProgressBar bar;
     TextView txt;
     int total=0;
     boolean isRunning=false;
     // handler for the background updating
     Handler handler=new Handler() {
         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
             total=total+5;
             String perc=String.valueOf(total).toString();
             txt.setText(perc+"% completed");
             bar.incrementProgressBy(5);
         }
     };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading_bar);
        bar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // reset the bar to the default value of 0
        bar.setProgress(0);
          // create a thread for updating the progress bar
         Thread background=new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 try {
                     for (int i=0;i<20 && isRunning;i++) {
                         // wait 1000ms between each update
                         Thread.sleep(1000);
                         handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
                     }
                 }
                 catch (Throwable t) {  

                 }     
             }    
         });

         isRunning=true;
         // start the background thread
         background.start();
     }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        isRunning=false;
     }
}
```

And with this I call it on another activity:

```
public void onClick (View v)
        {
            switch (v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.buttonNext3:
                Intent Loading = new Intent(this, Loading.class);
                startActivity(Loading);
                getContent();               
            Call();             
                db.generation();
                Intent Next3 = new Intent(this, FoodPlanning.class);
                startActivity(Next3);
                break;
            }

        }
```

But it is not work on mine, it just show blackscreen but it still on progress .... I want the loading bar appear when I click the button and the process still on progress. any idea? Thx u

Comment: Use [`AsyncTask`](http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=android+AsyncTask+wiht+progressBar) instead of `Thread`

Comment: I see you use `startActivity(Loading)` to start the Loading Activity, but immediately you call `startActivity(Next3)`, so Loading Activity stops.

Comment: but that just appear blackscreen for Loading, then after finish I want start the other activity

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Adil, AsyncTask is the preferred method to run background tasks with easy options to run certain commands on the UI thread, while pushing the rest to the background.  See this example from the SDK (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
}
```

Note the "onProgressUpdate" method as well as the doInBackground.

Comment: what is the method of Downloader ?

Comment: Michelle, its just an example code I pulled out the page in the SDK.  If you want to download files, I usually just do so with a HttpClient specifying the correct accept mime-type and writing it with an outputstream.